# How to use if_existing statment with path string?

Tags: linux, if-statement, conky

Im trying to chech if the file exists in conky using ${if_existing ..} as follows:

```
    ${if_existing /home/stanislav/.cache/yandexweather/bkn_n.png}YES \
    ${else}NO
    ${endif}\
```

And this works perfectly. However how can I use ${if_existing ..} statement with an output of another command? For Example:

```
    ${if_existing echo "~/.cache/yandexweather/"$(python ~/.cache/yandexweather/yw_script.py -image_0)}YES \
    ${else}NO
    ${endif}\
```

The latter doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `${eval ...}` to have the shell command calculated first, then having the `${if_...}` part parsed.  For example,

```
${eval $${if_existing ${execi 10 echo "myfile"}}\
          YES $${else} NO $${endif} }
```

Inside the eval, the `if..` `else` and `endif` parts are made to not work by doubling the `$` to `$$`. However, the `${execi` part runs and executes the shell command (`echo ...`) every 10 seconds (choose a big value if your expression will never change).

After the execi has returned the string (`myfile`, in this example), the resulting command is parsed again. Each `$$` has been evaluated to `$`, so we have:

```
${if_existing myfile} YES ${else} NO ${endif}
```

Comment: Well, it seems like a proper way but i still cant get to work the following sentence: `${eval $${if_existing ${exec echo $HOME"/.cache/yandexweather/"$(python ~/.cache/yandexweather/yw_script.py -image_0)}}
YES
$${else}
No
$${exec curl -s ${exec python ~/.cache/yandexweather/yw_script.py -image_0_url} -o /home/stanislav/.cache/yandexweather/${exec python ~/.cache/yandexweather/yw_script.py -image_0}}
$${endif}}`  . Actually I try to check if the file exists, and if not , i want to download it.

Comment: There are problems at startup as conky seems not to run the exec on the first iteration, so you can end up with a syntax error for `if_existing`. I think for something as complicated as you have, you should write a simple shell script to do the whole if..else..endif, and then just call it from conky with `${execi }`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It should be easier to use an additional script.